# using python's mpmath module how do I initialize mpf with a hexadecimal number?

Tags: python, mpmath

I would like to load a very large hexadecimal number into one of mpmath's mpf objects.  I tried

```
from mpmath import mp, mpf
a = mpf('0x100') # starting small here
```

but it malfunctioned:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0x100'
```

Simply using long integer constants appears to lose precision as well:

```
>>> mpf.prec = 300
>>> a = mpf( 0x123444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444)
>>> print("%x"%a)
123444444444440000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> a = mpf( 123444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444)
>>> print("%d"%a)
123444444444444452865502098927835995454229086812688745177808896
```

What is the proper technique for initializing an mpf instance from a hexadecimal string?

Comment: Are you trying to work with hexadecimal representation of an integer or a floating point number?

Answer (score 0):

Python understands hexadecimal by using prefixes; you almost got it: just remove the quotes:

```
a = mpf(0x100) # starting small here
```

Now where this breaks depends on how big is your number. If it does not fit within a Python integer it is automatically upgraded to a long integer (which is of arbitrary length (in Python 3 this is the default). Therefore it should "just work" out of the box, without the need to worry about special data types. 
You should be able to handle any hexadecimal number, as long as you have enough memory for it.

Comment: I am definitely going for specialty use.  I'm trying to validate python-generated OpenCL source code that does fixed-precision math (think 384 or 1600 bits).  0x100 was just a toy case.  I was targeting something that has like 96 hex digits.

Comment: @Bob I understand. I did a tiny bit of research for you and updated the answer: Python won't care (up to a point) how many digits your number has, it will handle it.

Comment: I attempted to implement your ideas and found another malfunction (which is now added to the question).  Do you have a code sample that works?